# No Error, but record not created

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got an html form that creates an invoice record in a database.  When the form submits, the message "Invoice Created" is displayed and there are no error messages.  However, when I go into the database, the record clearly isn't there.  I have a very similar form that adds customer records and it is working just fine.

The pertinent section of my php code (the connection code is working fine and I've omitted it):

```
if(isset( $_POST["add"]) ) {
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssissddd", $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['invoice_num'], $_POST['item_num'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['discount'], $_POST['total'])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

else{
    printf("%d row inserted.<br/>", $stmt->affected_rows);
}

$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure $_POST["add"] is set?  If it isn't then none of the rest would execute. Is "%d row inserted" being printed?

Comment: Advice: you should create a complete `INSERT` query (with column declaration): in such a way, if someday you add a column in that table, you'll not need to update your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  It was, but when I was checking the html code, I spotted a missing element.  It's working perfectly now.